# When can we prescribe the speed of a normal flow from a hypersurface?

Tags: cauchy-problem

Suppose that $X_0:M^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a smooth embedding of a compact hypersurface.  I'm given a scalar function $\eta \in C^{\infty}\left( M \times [0, T) \right)$ and I'd like to solve the problem

$$ \frac{dX}{dt}(x,t) = \eta(x,t)\vec{N}(x,t) $$
$$ X(\cdot, 0) = X_0  $$ where

$\vec{N}(x,t)$ is the unit normal vector determined by the embedding $$X( \cdot, t) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $$

What conditions does $\eta$ have to satisfy in order to guarantee that the solution exists, even for some short time?

If everything in sight is analytic, Cauchy-Kovalevskaya should do the trick, but can this be weakened to smooth?

Comment: Shall we assume that your normal vector always has length = 1 ?

Comment: yes, the unit normal